# Trying to prevent the opening of an angular material dialog while opening another one

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material2

I'm using the Angular Material Dialogs for events management in a grid calendar.

```
<td *ngFor="let member of members | async" (click)="openDialogNewEvent(time,member)">
    <div *ngFor="let event of events">
        <span *ngIf="event.time===member.time" (click)="openDialogSeeEvent(event)">.</span>
    </div></td>
```

The clickable span launching the second dialog :

```
openDialogSeeEvent(event)
```

is in the clickable td cell that launch the first dialog :

```
openDialogNewEvent(time,member)
```

It used to work like that but with the last angular material update, it seems that the two dialogs open when there is a click on the span.

I'm trying to find a way to prevent opening the openDialogNewEvent when clicking on the openDialogSeeEvent but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
openDialogSeeEvent(event1, event2) {
  event1.stopPropagation();
  // more code
}
```

And in html page:

```
(click)="openDialogSeeEvent($event, event)"
```

Comment: thanks Notmfb for your answer. I have the following error when I had the line : "ERROR TypeError: event.stopPropagation is not a function". And it seems to close the first dialog "openDialogNewEvent"...

Comment: I made a mistake in my question. I'm actually trying to prevent opening the openDialogNewEvent when clicking on openDialogSeeEvent...

Comment: Right. The function stopPropagation() will stop bubbling up to parent events. I think the reason you're still getting the error is because you aren't sending the actual Angular event to the function. You have "openDialogSeeEvent(event)" - Change it to this "openDialogSeeEvent($event)" and it should work

Comment: yes It actually block the other Dialog If I add "$event". But I loose all the data that was in the event variable.

Comment: Then the event is holding different information. So simply send both. See my edit above

Comment: perfect that is exactly what I've done. Many thanks for your help!